# L'Hopital's Rule Complication

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

$\textrm{Let } f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{g(x)}{x}~, & \!\! x \neq 0 \\ 0~, & \!\! x = 0 \end{cases} \textrm{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.$

$\textrm{Assume } g(0) = g'(0) = 0 \wedge g''(0) = 17.$

$\textrm{Want To Prove } f'(0) = \displaystyle\frac{17}{2}.$

Information Necessary For The Use Of L'Hopital's Rule:
[Important Lemmas](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1llWJsMGnTwawPklxELbrihTbsmDd6YTB/view?usp=sharing)

I showed that $f$ is continuous at $0$ so that $f'(0)$ can be computed using the limit definition.

In order to compute $f'(0)$, I wish to use L'Hopital's Rule (LHR).

$f'(0)$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0 + x) - f(0)}{x}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - 0}{x}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\displaystyle\frac{g(x)}{x}}{x}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x)}{x^2}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{g'(x)}{2x}~~~$ According to LHR: [Justification](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rGSAsy_Sc7I2W1ovTgXq_NgPgHGxtyOU/view?usp=sharing)

In order to get $\displaystyle\frac{17}{2}$, I must use L'Hopital's Rule again to get $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{g''(x)}{2}$.

However, so far, I cannot show that $g''(x)$ is never $0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, which is an important property justifying the use of LHR.

In other words, I have no continuity assumption or third derivative to prove there exists an interval containing $0$ where $g''(x)$ is never $0$, using the information I have derived.

This is my attempt so far of justifying my second use of LHR:
[Justification 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EdtWWVO49gJXc3pHmJE3qs4ZIYh8fhZ3/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, I am missing the final step regarding $g''(x)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Let me know if there is any function $g$ where $f'(0)$ wouldn't be $\displaystyle\frac{17}{2}$, in which case I must assume something about $g$ or $g''$.

Comment: Why do you believe that $g''(x)$ must never be $0$ as $x\to 0$?  It is $\frac{d}{dx}(2x)$ that is not permitted to be $0$ near $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we need not appeal to L'Hospital's Rule.  If $f'(0)$ exists, then it is equal to the limit given by

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}f'(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x}{x}\\\\
&=\frac12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-2g(0)+g(-x)}{x^2}\\\\
&=\frac12g''(0)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

---

Alternatively, we may apply L'Hospital's Rule once and write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}f'(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x}{x}\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{LHR}}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g'(x)}{2x}\\\\
&=\frac12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g'(x)-g'(0)}{x}\\\\
&=\frac12g''(0)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

if $\phi(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, and also $\psi(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, and if you are interested in

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\,\frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)},$$

and if also $\phi$ and $\psi$ are differentiable at $0$, then

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\,\frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)}\,=\,\frac{\phi'(0)}{\psi'(0)},$$

if it also is true that $\psi'(0)$ is not zero. This lemma is enough for your problem.

You want to show:

$$f'(0)\,=\,\lim_{h \to 0}\,\frac{f(h)}{h}\,=\,\lim_{h \to 0}\,\frac{g(h)}{h^2}\,=\,\frac{17}{2}.$$

By L'hopital, since $g$ is continuous at zero,

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\,\frac{g(h)}{h^2}\,=\,\lim_{h \to 0}\,\frac{g'(h)}{2h},$$

if the latter exists. We have again a "zero/zero" form, since $g'$ is continuous at zero. But $g'$ is in fact differentiable at zero, so we use the lemma:

$$\,\lim_{h \to 0}\,\frac{g'(h)}{2h}\,=\,\frac{g''(0)}{2}.$$

(*Alternatively -- as pointed out by Mark Viola -- this last result follows directly from the definition of $g''(0)$.*)

Comment: This lemma you mention should assume that phi ' (x) is never 0 as x approaches 0 (for x near 0 but not equal to 0). That is what's stopping me from applying the last step.

Comment: Oh nevermind, you were right. I was confused between the numerator and denominator.

Comment: You seem to have assumed that $\lim_{h\to0}g''(h)=g''(0)$.

Comment: @MarkViola  quite right, we cannot assume $g''$ has a limit there. But I think I have avoided such an assumption. In the very last step, I do use that $g'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Hence the very last limit is a "zero/zero" form, but with both numerator and denominator differentiable at zero. Thus I think my lemma(\phi and \psi story above) kicks in.

Comment: @311411 Note that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g'(h)}{2h}=\frac12 \lim_{h\to0}\frac{g'(h)-g(0)}{h}=\frac12 g''(0)$ by definition of the derivative of $g''(0)$.